# Complexity of np.argsort()

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, space-complexity

Is there a difference in memory consumption or between np.argsort(array)[::-1][:10] and np.argsort(array)[-10:]?

they both return the same numbers (same answer) but my university doctor said that the first one is worst because it takes up more space using make a new descending array , so I want to make sure .

Comment: Only one way to be sure: measure both.

Comment: @AKX it's documented behavior that those slices create views

Comment: To check the actual behavior, you can use [shares_memory](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.shares_memory.html) or [byte_bounds](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.byte_bounds.html).

Comment: `timeit` applied to `argsort(x[::-1])` and `argsort(x)` is nearly the same, just enough different to account for the`[::-1]` view creation.

Answer (score 0):

No, for `numpy.ndarray` objects, those slices create *views*, and creating a view only requires a small, constant amount of extra space.

[From the docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#slicing-and-striding):

> All arrays generated by basic slicing are always views of the original
> array.

Your professor is probably assuming that slicing works the same was as with built-in `list` objects, which indeed would require extra copies.

Comment: (Though depending on what's done with the view, it might require a copy down the line; I learned that the hard way with Torch interop...)